# How to define a new XML namespace in an XmlNode with a different prefix in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

I've got an XmlNode that I create like this:

```
XmlNode nodeSecurity = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "wsse", "Security", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
```

The result looks like this:

```
<wsse:Security />
```

The wsse-Namespace has already been declared by a parent node, so this node does not contain an "xmlns:wsse='...'"-attribute (unknown namespaces would have been declared in an automatic xmlns-attribute).

Now my problem:
I need to declare a new namespace here, so the result looks like this:

```
<wsse:Security wsu:xmlns='....' />
```

I tried to add an attribute like this:

```
XmlNode attr = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Attribute, "wsu", "blabla");
 nodeSecurity.Attributes.SetNamedItem(attr);
```

And the result is:

```
<wsse:Security p4:wsu="" xmlns:p4="blabla" />
```

Instead of:

```
<wsse:Security wsu:xmlns="blabla" />
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
XmlAttribute attr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("wsu", "xmlns", "namespace");
attr.Value = "blabla";
nodeSecurity.Attributes.Append(attr);
```

Result

```
<wsse:Security wsu:xmlns="blabla" xmlns:wsu="namespace" />
```

In this case, `wsu:xmlns` is an attribute with the name `xmlns` and prefix `wsu`. The namespace belonging to the prefix set in the form `xmlns:wsu`.

Comment: Yes, that helped. Thank you :)